# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Stripe.framework/Stripe

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe Payment Gateway in my iOS application. Which is on Xcode 8.2 with 10.2 simulator.

My application Build getting successful. But after building it, It says.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Stripe.framework/Stripe
>
> Referenced from: 
>       /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D27A4EC3-3B8A-4BBC-AB30-E9313AD95E1E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/225274C8-EB99-476A-88A3-6F9981948220/Test App.app/Test App
>
> Reason: image not found

Here is Bit of Code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    registerForPushNotifications(application)
    spinnerInitialization();
    //STRIPE CONFIGURATION 
    Stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey("pk_test_YdACg6uENGmWrSWwAy00gWUx")
   return true
}
```

Comment: Did you add framework to `Link Binary with Sources`? And which dependency manager did you use? Carthage?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov Yes this is connected, I am not using Carthage i did just drag and drop `Stripe.framework` in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to project select General and add your framework to Embedded Binaries section [image]

Comment: Thanks Brother it's worked for me, But when i add framework in `Embedded Binaries section` then another framework is added to `Linked frameworks and libraries`. Is there any problem for that.....

Comment: No it did not create any problem